# there is a way to detect is layout has scroll of any kind?

Tags: android

there is a quick way to detect if layout can be scrolled?
as far as i know there is several view types that can be scrolled like scrollView, recyclerView, listView and etc. 
i am looking for option to do it quick.

My main goal is to check if layout height is bigger that screen height and let say that my layout can be:

```
<ScrollView>
<Linearlayout>
<constraintlayout>
<ScrollView>
<constraintlayout>
....
```

its just an exmaple.

a complex layout and not simple. thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible like this,

First of all, you need to calculate the height of the screen itself, use this

```
 public int getScreenHeight() {
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) application.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    return display.getHeight();
}
```

After that you need to calculate the view height that you want to know whether is scrollable or not. Use this

```
yourView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            yourView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            yourView.getHeight(); //height is ready

            //combine them here
        }
    });
```

So basically if the height of your view is greater than the screen itself, it means it is scrollable

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely yes. Add an Android ID to your ScrollView.

```
NestedScrollView scroller = findViewById(R.id.myScroll);
scroller.setOnScrollChangeListener((NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener) (v, scrollX, scrollY, oldScrollX, oldScrollY) -> {

    if (scrollY > oldScrollY) {
        // when user scrolls down set toolbar elevation to 4dp
        toolbar.setElevation(4);
        toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.colorToolbar));
    }
    if (scrollY < oldScrollY) {
        // when user scrolls up keep toolbar elevation at 4dp
        toolbar.setElevation(4);
        toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.colorToolbar));
    }

    if (scrollY == 0) {
        // if user is not scrolling it means
        // that he is at top of page 
        toolbar.setElevation(1); // required or it will overlap linear layout
        toolbar.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); // required to delete elevation shadow
    }
});
```

This code is an example for a NestedScrollView on how to handle toolbar elevation on scrolling.